# Pick the $\zeta(3)$ contribution from Gamma function countour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I edited the post and title.

How do we see that given
$$ Z= \oint \frac{d \epsilon}{2\pi i} (z\bar z)^{-\epsilon}
\frac{\pi^4 \sin 5\pi \epsilon}{\sin^5 \pi \epsilon} \left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^k \frac{\Gamma(1+5k-5\epsilon)}{\Gamma(1+k-\epsilon)^5}\right|^2,$$
where complex conjugation does not act on $\epsilon$, the coefficient of $\zeta(3)$ term in $Z$ is given by $X^0(z) \overline{ X^0(z)}$ where
$$X^0(z)=\sum_k (-z)^k \frac{\Gamma(1+5k)}{\Gamma(1+k)^5}$$
as discussed in eq. 4.6 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6244) ?

Comment: The function $\sin(5\pi z)/ \sin^5(\pi z)$ is invariant under $z\leftrightarrow -z$, so the contour integral over a small circle around the origin is $0$. Is the integrand written correctly?

Comment: I agree with @JulianRosen: the Laurent series about $z=0$ only has terms even in $z$, so the residue is zero.

Comment: And why is your title general with $n$ and the question specific?

Comment: Quote:  "Is it true, that ...?"  No.

Comment: @ jj-p:what made you think the integral is related to apery's constant?

Comment: I tried to improve the question

Answer (score 1):

$z=0$ is an isolated singularity for $f(z)=\frac{\sin(5\pi z)}{\sin^5(\pi z)}$, in particular a pole of order four with residue zero (since $f$ is an even function). By the Cauchy's integral formula it follows that the integral is just zero.